# Meaning of "weasel of a friend"

Tags: meaning

I was looking for the meaning of the word "weasel", and when I found it on " vocabluary.com" I came across an unfamiliar, to me, usage of "of". Here is the excerpt from it. "A  weasel is a sly and sneaky person. Your weasel of a friend has a habit of "forgetting" his wallet every time he goes out to dinner with you." what does "your weasel of a friend" there mean? Does that mean that your weasel is your friend? I cannot catch on this usage of the of phrase.

Comment: It means 'Your friend is a weasel'.

Comment: Your friend has a sly and sneaky way to avoid paying for dinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure, which I doubt exists in any other language aside from English, is used to describe a noun ("friend", in this case) with another noun ("weasel"), which acts as its modifier. If the main noun takes a possessive as in this case, the possessive is transferred to the modifier (your friend, who is a weasel => your weasel of a friend)

Other examples are:

- Your angel of a wife has taken care of everything (Your wife, who is an angel, has taken care of everything).
- He has a devil of a boss (= a boss who is a devil).
- She is a goddess of a girl.

I find this structure unique in that, instead of using an adjective, which would lose semantic force as well as idiomatic effectiveness ("your weasel of a friend" is much more descriptive than "your sneaky, sly friend"), in the mind of the speaker the other person's friend IS (metaphorically speaking) a weasel. More than a mere comparison, this structure establishes a relationship of equality, which I find it to be close to a metaphor.

Comment: I am also wondering if it is correct by saying "your weasel friend"?